# Hibernate mapping entities not present in persistence.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using `persistence.xml` to specify my mapping setting in Hibernate. That is I am using the EntityManager class to get my transactions.

Now I have the following classes listed in my `persistence.xml`

```
<class>test.entity.Course</class>
<class>test.entity.Semester</class>
<class>test.entity.Subject</class>
```

Also in my Eclipse project I have two more classes (Student.java and User.java) that are marked with the `@Entity` annotation but are not listed in the `persistence.xml` file.

But when I run my project Hibernate actually maps those two classes as well. What I mean is that it creates database tables for those two classes as well (I have `hbm2ddl` set to `auto`).

Why is it doing this ? Isn't it suppose to map only the files listed in  `persistence.xml` ?

Comment: How do you get an instance of EntityManager? In which environment is your app running?

Comment: @JBNizet Through the `entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, JPA standard states, that in application server environment, all classes annotated with @Entity are considered, whether they are listed in persistence.xml or not.
If you really want to include only those 3 entities mentioned in persistence.xml, you need to add following setting into your persistence.xml file into the persistence-unit element:

```
<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

Comment: @OndejM Yup you were right. Now I get the expected behaviour. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Hibernate can be configured with either persistence.xml or with JPA annotations.

Comment: Wait I am using both. So am I suppose to use just one ?

Comment: Yup, unless you need both for some reason. Annotations are the recommended approach, but either one works.

Comment: If its just annotations where would keep the connection settings like the password and Connection String ? And also where would you specify the hbm2ddl value ? The only place where you can place these are the `persistence.xml ` file.

Comment: I disagree with Tyler on this. You may combine annotations with mapping in persistence.xml. It works, it only is not recommended. Both settings are combined and if there is a conflicting setting, values in persistence.xml overwrite values in annotations. This way you can overwrite settings from an external library, as you may not be able to change annotations on commpiled code, but you are always able to modify persistence.xml file.

Comment: @OndrejM makes a good point about overriding things in a read only library, I hadn't thought about that.